# Create a network graph from array of objects

Tags: java

i would like to Add to the class Network <Vertex extends Comparable <? super
Vertex >> a new public Network (Vertex [] V) constructor method that
construct a complete directed graph whose vertices are the objects in V,
labeled on the arcs with all unit weights.

this is my code:

```
 public Network( Vertex[] V) {
    adjacencyMap = new TreeMap<Vertex, TreeMap<Vertex, Double>>();
    //adding vertex
    for (int i=0; i < V.length; i++)
        adjacencyMap.put (V[i], new TreeMap<Vertex, Double>());   //addVertex(V[i]);
```

but now how do i add the arcs for each node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph is given by an adjacency list. You can add the neighbors of a node `V[i]` using the following snippet:

`adjacencyMap.get(V[i]).put(V[j], d)`,

where `V[i]` is the current graph node, `V[j]` is a neighbor of the current node, and `d` is the weight of the arc between `V[i]` and `V[j]`.

Since you have a complete graph with unit weights you can define another `for` loop and iterate through all vertices adding their neighbors alongside with the weights (all 1's in your case).

Comment: So I have to do another loop and insert the vertices in the neighborMap with weight d?



`code` TreeMap<Vertex, Double> neighborMap = adjacencyMap.get (V[i]); 
neighborMap.put(V[J] , 1.0); 
`code`

Comment: It depends on your business logic. If you have a complete graph then yes, add every vertex (except itself) to the map of neighbors and the weights between the vertices (as I get it they all will be set to 1.0).